# Angular2. Замена компонентов при событии

Tags: angular2

К примеру имеем такое:

```
<body>
    <form-component>
        <index-component></index-component>
    </form-component>
</body>
```

При нажатии кнопки в `form-component` как заменить `index-component`, на(например) `enter-component`.

P.S. Url менять не надо, т.е. это должно быть на одной странице, без маршрутизации.

P.P.S. Я думал что есть более правильный вариант для этих целей, это ведь Angular2 :) его так хвалят, а ngIf мне кажется не совсем правильный вариант, хоть и может сработать. Я попробую ngIf, но я стремлюсь использовать технологии правильно. Например если таких компонентов будет более 10ти? Мне кажется ngIf будет не совсем лучшим решением.

Comment: например использовать `ngIf` и какое-то булевое свойство показывающее какой  из компонентов  показывать

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать структурные директивы: [здесь](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/) достаточно ясные примеры использования. В частности, `<ng-template>` используется в для создания т. н. *editors* - виджетов-редакторов ячеек в таблицах (там чаще всего два отображения - вьювер и редактор).

И использование ngIf в данном случае достаточно оправдано, во всяком случае в сравнении с динамическим инстансом компонентов.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="lessons" [ngIfElse]="loading">
   <div class="lessons-list">
        ... 
   </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loading>
   <div>Loading...</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #lessons>
   <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       ...
   </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на русскоязычный StackOverflow и спасибо за ответ! Чтобы сделать его более полным и полезным как отвечающим, так и будущим посетителям, пожалуйста, дополните его примером, не ограничиваясь ссылкой на сторонний блог.

Answer (score -1):

Вот статья как это делается правильно - http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/.
Нужно использовать entryComponents в декораторе чтобы фреймворк знал какие фабрики компонентов ему понадобятся. 
Можно компилить любой компонент на лету и без entryComponents но тогда вам понадобится Compiler from angular/core, который не доступен в Ahead of Time compilation. То есть полностью динамическая компиляция компонента когда вы не знаете что будет скомпилировано в нутри текущего компонента доступна только в JIT.